# Attempt to create 'Virtual Directory' creates 'Virtual Application' instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a web application that deploys with two virtual directories under it's IIS virtual application.  On IIS 6 boxes, the following code creates these virtual directories as expected, however on IIS 7 boxes, I end up with my virtual application having two other virtual applications under it, rather than one virtual application with two virtual directories under it.  I've tried the following two methods, but both still create a virtual application, not a virtual directory.  How can this code be changed to deploy the needed virtual directories, not the undesired virtual applications?

one:

```
private void AddVirtualDir(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    DirectoryEntry virtualDirectory = (DirectoryEntry)entry.Invoke("Create", "IIsWebVirtualDir", "VirtualDirectory");
    virtualDirectory.InvokeSet("Path", @"VirtualPath");
    virtualDirectory.InvokeSet("AppFriendlyName", "VirtualDirectory");
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessRead"][0] = true;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = 512;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AppIsolated"].Clear();
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AppIsolated"].Add(2);
    virtualDirectory.Invoke("AppCreate", false);
    virtualDirectory.CommitChanges();
    entry.CommitChanges();
}
```

two:

```
private void AddVirtualDir(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    var virtualDirectory = entry.Children.Add("VirtualDirectory", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessRead"][0] = true;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = 512;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = "EditorControls";
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AppIsolated"][0] = 2;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["Path"][0] = Path.Combine(_INSTALLDIR, @"Kryptiq_Root\FormManagement\EditorControls");
    virtualDirectory.CommitChanges();
    entry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what this looks like in IIS6 (remember to expand all the necessary nodes), I'm having trouble working out what this should look like. Also the two examples given, are these two different things you tried?

Comment: Yes, the two different things are two different ways I tried.  Your suggestion works great on IIS 7.  At the moment, it seems like IIS 6 isn't getting the asp.net extensions set, which I am investigating.

Comment: On talking with QA, the current IIS 6 issue doesn't seem to involve the virtual directories of this change.  The whole virtual app that gets created doesn't have the .net extensions.  I'm investigating the other code changes to my config file unrelated to this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How this works on IIS6

The problem here is that you're setting the [`AppIsolated`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bd29f59f-7e75-49bb-9146-71b0db817187.mspx?mfr=true) value. In IIS6 this is used to configure how an application should run, and generally you should never need to touch this or add it anywhere.

`AppIsolated` always defaults to `2` which means pooled process, i.e. the application will run in either the parent application's application pool or in the pool specified by  [`AppPoolId`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bd29f59f-7e75-49bb-9146-71b0db817187.mspx?mfr=true).

The reason that there are other values is so that you can configure an application to run in a couple of legacy IIS5 modes - In Process and Out of Process mode.

So unless you configured your site's `/root` application to run as anything other than `AppIsolated="2"` then you don't need to set this value.

Your code can be as simple as:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT"))
{
  using (DirectoryEntry virtualDirectory = entry.Children.Add("MyVdir", 
                                           "IIsWebVirtualDir"))
  {
    virtualDirectory.Properties["Path"][0] = PATH_TO_MY_STUFF;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessRead"][0] = true;
    virtualDirectory.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = 512;
    virtualDirectory.CommitChanges();
  }
}
```

If you do set `AppIsolated` in IIS6 it gets ignored because for the directory to become an application you also need to set [`AppRoot`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bd29f59f-7e75-49bb-9146-71b0db817187.mspx?mfr=true).

#### IIS7 - IIS6 compatibility shim

In IIS7 when using `System.DirectoryServices` you're working with an underlying II6 compatibility API which is translating these ADSI calls to calls to the new IIS7 API. It's not perfect and I suspect that when it see's `AppIsolated` being set it's assuming you want an application, despite you not specifying any other application related metabase values.

#### IIS7 Managed API is better

You probably know this, but it's better to work with IIS7 configuration via the managed [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) bits. Not all of the ADSI/metabase compatibility settings have equivalents in IIS7 which can force the translation layer to make compromises to work around this. I mention these types of problems in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227319/419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189250/419).